# How to add multiple JAR files in classpath (via terminal)

Tags: java, classpath, command-line-arguments

I was wondering if I get help in regard to adding up multiple JAR files in class path via terminal or via eclipse.

I use Eclipse on ubuntu & my lib folder with JARS lies under project folder, I've tried to add jars on the classpath through eclipse "java build path", but it is weird because it shows only .system folder under project folder while clicking on add JARs , no lib folder exist.

Grateful for the help
I already went some solutions on stack but didn't help me.

Comment: Are you adding your libraries manually? If so I would highly recommend looking at a tool such as Maven or Gradle to take care of this for you

Comment: No, I don't use Maven or Gradle for the moment, just practice simple spring

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including all the jars in a directory within the Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

Comment: Spring is a pretty extensive framework, and has quite a few component libraries, each with dependencies of its own. Managing this manually is a pretty big distraction from actually learning to use any of these components, even the simpler ones.

Comment: Jeroen, yes you are right I conclude it with Maven instead of wasting the time, actually it was course requirement

Comment: Vlad I already went across but it didn't help